# how to loop through folders thoroughly? python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm new to python and get stuck by a problem I encountered while studying loops and folder navigation.

The task is simple: loop through a folder and count all '.txt' files.

I believe there may be some modules to tackle this task easily and I would appreciate it if you can share them. But since this is just a random question I encountered while learning python, it would be nice if this can be solved using the tools I just acquired, like for/while loops.

I used for and while clauses to loop through a folder. However, I'm unable to loop through a folder entirely.

Here is the code I used:

```py
import os
count=0 # set count default
path = 'E:\\' # set path
while os.path.isdir(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path): # loop through the folder
        print(file)   # print text to keep track the process
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            count+=1
            print('+1')   #
        elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path,file)): #if it is a subfolder
            print(os.path.join(path,file))
            path=os.path.join(path,file)
            print('is dir')
            break
        else:
            path=os.path.join(path,file)
```

Since the number of files and subfolders in a folder is unknown, I think a while loop is appropriate here. However, my code has many errors or pitfalls I don't know how to fix. for example, if multiple subfolders exist, this code will only loop the first subfolder and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you quickly end up trying to look at non-existent files. Imagine a directory structure where a non-directory named `A` (`E:\A`) is seen first, then a file `b` (`E:\b`).

On your first loop, you get `A`, detect it does not end in `.txt`, and that it is a directory, so you change `path` to `E:\A`.

On your second iteration, you get `b` (meaning `E:\b`), but all your tests (aside from the `.txt` extension test) and operations concatenate it with the new `path`, so you test relative to `E:\A\b`, not `E:\b`.

Similarly, if `E:\A` *is* a directory, you break the inner loop immediately, so even if `E:\c.txt` exists, if it occurs after `A` in the iteration order, you never even see it.

Directory tree traversal code must involve a stack of some sort, either explicitly (by `append`ing and `pop`ing from a `list` of directories for eventual processing), or implicitly (via recursion, which uses the call stack to achieve the same purpose).

In any event, your specific case should really just be handled [with `os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    print(root) # print text to keep track the process
    count += sum(1 for f in files if f.endswith('txt'))

    # This second line matches your existing behavior, but might not be intended
    # Remove it if directories ending in .txt should not be included in the count
    count += sum(1 for d in files if d.endswith('txt'))
```

Just for illustration, the explicit stack approach to your code would be something like:

```
import os
count = 0  # set count default
paths = ['E:\\']  # Make stack of paths to process
while paths:
    # paths.pop() gets top of directory stack to process
    # os.scandir is easier and more efficient than os.listdir,
    # though it must be closed (but with statement does this for us)
    with os.scandir(paths.pop()) as entries:
        for entry in entries:  # loop through the folder
            print(entry.name)  # print text to keep track the process
            if entry.name.endswith('.txt'):
                count += 1
                print('+1')
            elif entry.is_dir():  #if it is a subfolder
                print(entry.path, 'is dir')
                # Add to paths stack to get to it eventually
                paths.append(entry.path)
```

Comment: The os.walk() works elegantly. Just out of curiosity, do you know the code for os.walk() (or the way to find the code for a function)?  I tried to look through the os module documentation with no luck.

Comment: @Muchdecal: The entire CPython code base is available on GitHub. [This is `os.walk`'s source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/os.py#L278). If you're using `ipython` interactively (I highly recommend it as a replacement for normal interactive use), you can see the source code for any function implemented in Python (but not C extension code) with the `??` pseudo-operator, e.g. `os.walk??`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to apply [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) to this problem. In short, you will need a function to handle directories that will call itself when it encounters a sub-directory.

Comment: Recursion isn't strictly necessary (and in Python, which has limited stack depth that could be overloaded by too deep directory trees, not a great idea). All you really need is a stack of paths to traverse; a simple `list` provides that functionality without recursion.

Answer (score 0):

for nested Directories it's easier to use functions like `os.walk`
take this for example

```
subfiles = []
for dirpath, subdirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for x in files:
        if x.endswith(".txt"):
            subfiles.append(os.path.join(dirpath, x))`
```

and it'ill return a list of all txt files
else ull need to use Recursion for task like this

Answer (score 0):

This might be more than you need, but it will allow you to list all the files within the directory that are .txt files but you can also add criteria to the search within the files as well.  Here is the function:

```py
def file_search(root,extension,search,search_type):
    import pandas as pd
    import os
    col1 = []
    col2 = []
    rootdir = root
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            if "." + extension in file.lower():
                try:
                    with open(os.path.join(subdir, file)) as f:
                        contents = f.read()
                    if search_type == 'any':
                        if any(word.lower() in contents.lower() for word in search):
                            col1.append(subdir)
                            col2.append(file)

                    elif search_type == 'all':
                        if all(word.lower() in contents.lower() for word in search):
                            col1.append(subdir)
                            col2.append(file)
                except:
                    pass
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Folder':col1,
                      'File':col2})[['Folder','File']]
    return df
```

Here is an example of how to use the function:

```py
search_df = file_search(root = r'E:\\',
                        search=['foo','bar'], #words to search for
                        extension = 'txt',    #could change this to 'csv' or 'sql' etc.
                        search_type = 'all')  #use any or all

search_df
```

Answer (score 0):

The analysis of your code has already been addressed by @ShadowRanger's answer quite well.
I will try to address this part of your question:

> there may be some modules to tackle this task easily

For these kind of tasks, there actually exists the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/glob.html) module, which implements Unix style pathname pattern expansion.

To count the number of `.txt` files in a directory and all its subdirectories, one may simply use the following:

```py
import os
from glob import iglob, glob  

dirpath = '.'  # for example

# getting all matching elements in a list a computing its length
len(glob(os.path.join(dirpath, '**/*.txt'), recursive=True))
# 772

# or iterating through all matching elements and summing 1 each time a new item is found
# (this approach is more memory-efficient)
sum(1 for _ in iglob(os.path.join(dirpath, '**/*.txt'), recursive=True))
# 772
```

Basically `glob.iglob()` is the iterator version of `glob.glob()`.